# NLP - when i'm "lowering" my text there are some words that are losing their frequency instead of adding more

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm training myself with some text data trying to do some simple actions on it. 
At first the word "Data" was with a frequency of 7, but then i found on the same text more words related to it "data", so i lowered all the text in order to gain the missing words.
the final frequency for "data" is only 3.
Can someone try to help me ?

```
## First Word Frequency calculation:

from nltk.corpus import stopwords

import string

stop_list = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)

tokens_no_stop = [token for token in tokens if token not in stop_list]

word_frequency_no_stop = Counter(tokens_no_stop)

for word, freq in word_frequency_no_stop.most_common(20):
     print(word, freq)
```

> Data 7
>
> projects 5
>
> People 4
>
> systems 4
>
> High 4

```
## Second Word Frequency calc:

all_tokens_lower = [t.lower() for t in word_frequency_no_stop] 

total_term_frequency_normalised = Counter(all_tokens_lower )

for word, freq in total_term_frequency_normalised.most_common(20):
    print(word, freq)
```

> data 2
>
> project 2
>
> management 2
>
> skills 2

Does someone can explain why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What's wrong with your code**

```
all_tokens_lower = [t.lower() for t in word_frequency_no_stop]
```

In above line use tokens instead of `word_frequency_no_stop`.

You have derived value of `word_frequency_no_stop` from

```
word_frequency_no_stop = Counter(tokens_no_stop)
```

which return a dict which will have each word only once.

In your case it is giving you count as 2 coz it will have Capitalize word and lowercase word.

eg. `word_frequency_no_stop = { 'Project': 7, 'project': 2}`

so it will return the count as 2 for other words as well

**Use below code**

```
stop_list = stopwords.words('english') + list(string.punctuation)

tokens_no_stop = [token.lower() for token in tokens if token not in stop_list]

word_frequency_no_stop = Counter(tokens_no_stop)

for word, freq in word_frequency_no_stop.most_common(20):
     print(word, freq)
```